# Random effect model: residual variance interpretation

Tags: econometrics, stata, panel-data, random-effects-model

I have ran a random effect regression to work with a panel data on Stata:

```
xtreg lc ly lpl lpm ,re
```

I got this output but I have some troubles in interpreting its results:

```
Random-effects GLS regression                   Number of obs      =       121
Group variable: firm                            Number of groups   =        11

R-sq:  within  = 0.9643                         Obs per group: min =        11
       between = 0.9807                                        avg =      11.0
       overall = 0.9754                                        max =        11

                                                Wald chi2(3)       =   3032.03
corr(u_i, X)   = 0 (assumed)                    Prob > chi2        =    0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          lc |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
          ly |   .7351906   .0296156    24.82   0.000     .6771451    .7932361
         lpl |   .4366157   .0715739     6.10   0.000     .2963334     .576898
         lpm |   .4501235   .0654581     6.88   0.000     .3218281    .5784189
       _cons |   3.545622   .3564893     9.95   0.000     2.846915    4.244328
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |  .14818641
     sigma_e |  .05634275
         rho |  .87369537   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My doubt regards the values of **sigma_u** and **sigma_e**. I do not understand if it is just a case of different notation between the output and my notes or if there is something I am missing.

In my notes, I have sigma_e as the within regression estimator and sigma_u is not really defined. When computing the FGLS-RE estimator for $\beta$ in the RE model, there appears a $\sigma_1$ defined as $\sigma_e + T\sigma_u$.

Thus, what is the meaning of these two values in the output? Does my $\sigma_1$ have any sense or is it just something to simplify computations?

**EDIT**:

I post here the output from a fixed effect regression in order to be more precise about the doubt I expressed in the comment to Ben's answer:

```
    . xtreg lc ly lpl lpm ,fe                         
>                                                 
> 

Fixed-effects (within) regression               Number of obs      =       121
Group variable: firm                            Number of groups   =        11

R-sq:  within  = 0.9660                         Obs per group: min =        11
       between = 0.9804                                        avg =      11.0
       overall = 0.9694                                        max =        11

                                                F(3,107)           =   1013.45
corr(u_i, Xb)  = 0.8088                         Prob > F           =    0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          lc |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
          ly |    .646557   .0351676    18.39   0.000     .5768413    .7162727
         lpl |   .4259417   .0678751     6.28   0.000     .2913872    .5604963
         lpm |   .4275717   .0621337     6.88   0.000      .304399    .5507445
       _cons |   3.789308   .3387089    11.19   0.000     3.117857    4.460759
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |  .27826716
     sigma_e |  .05634275
         rho |  .96061756   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
F test that all u_i=0:     F(10, 107) =    61.33             Prob > F = 0.0000
```

My question was about the presence of estimates of sigma_e and sigma_u also in a fixed effect model, even if sigma_u should not exist in the model: I mean in a random effect model we have a composite error but in a fixed effect one shouldn't be only sigma_e?

Comment: sigma_u and sigma_e are, respectively, estimates of the standard deviation of Ui (individual fixed effect) and e (stochastic error, i.e., it changes among individual and through time)

Comment: usually, first you run "xtreg, y x's,fe"  model, save the estimates; then tun "xtreg, y x's, re" model, save the estimates; finally, run the hausman test, to decide which one should be used (i.e., within etimator--also called fixed effects estimator--or random-effects estimaror).

Comment: @Fuca26 Ok, thus sigma_e should be $s^2_{LSDV}$, and sigma_u, $s^2_{B}$, where LSDV stands for Least Squares Dummy Variables estimator and B for Between estimator?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Now, you are using only the random-effect estimator, and the output concerns only this model. The last three lines just tell you how the variance of the error terms is composed. In the randome-effect estimator, you can get an estimate of the effects of certain time-specific characteristics (i.e., dummies for each year in your panel dataset); therefore, your composite error is formed only of individual-effects (the Ui) and the purely sthocastic error term (usually indicated as Eit, where E should be an epsilon).

Comment: @Fuca26 Maybe I should better explain my question. I'll edit

Comment: Unfortunately symbols change slightly depending on the book or notes you are reading. However, if it might be useful, I suggest to read this notes https://www.princeton.edu/~otorres/Panel101.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks good to me. If you intended to run a binary random effects model, then $\sigma_e^2$ would need to be set to an arbitrary value (most likely 1), but it looks like you're running a random effects model on a continuous response whereas both $\sigma_e$ and $\sigma_u$ are estimable quantities from the data.

That doesn't make interpretation of these quantities cake. I typically refer people to a [modern Intraclass Correlation (ICC) definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation#Modern_ICC_definitions:_simpler_formula_but_positive_bias), $$\frac{\sigma_u^2}{\sigma_u^2 + \sigma_e^2},$$ which in your case leads to $.14818641^2 / (.14818641^2 + .05634275^2) = 0.8736953,$ or $\rho$ in your printout. While it might be awkward to talk about $\sigma_u$ and $\sigma_e$ by themselves, this ratio (the ICC) can be interpreted analogous to a correlation coefficient, a concept many people are already comfortable with. The difference is, quoting the linked Wikipedia page, "*unlike most other correlation measures it operates on data structured as groups, rather than data structured as paired observations*."

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But, now I have a doubt: in random effect model the error is composite and its variance can be divided into $\sigma_u$ and $\sigma_e$ and that has a meaning. Now, if I run a fixed effect model I can see the same two values in my output even if I know that what I am looking at is a _within group_ regression. 
How can you explain this?

Comment: I guess I'm not really following. The procedure you showed appears to be a random effects procedure. Are you saying that when you run a fixed effects procedure, you still get an estimate of $\sigma_u$? In some balanced data situations (the kind you'd see in textbooks on ANOVA), the partitioning of the variance is exactly the same for fixed and random effects, but that wouldn't explain why a fixed effects procedure would report the variance of the random effects. Can you send me a link to this procedure's output?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have edited my question in order to be more precise about my question. The output is made with Stata, command xtreg.